# Spring Boot, Flyway, DB2 - Cannot overwrite Properties

Tags: spring-boot, db2, flyway

I tried to Update an application to a newer version of Spring Boot 2 and have now a problem during startup that I cannot explain myself.

Here the Log:

```
2020-05-28 09:23:41.408  INFO 10784 --- [           main] d.v.h.Application               : Starting Application on E0088856 with PID 10784 (_\target\classes started by _ in _)
2020-05-28 09:23:41.412  INFO 10784 --- [           main] d.v.h.Application               : The following profiles are active: server
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/_/Maven_Repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.5.11/groovy-2.5.11.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-05-28 09:23:42.927  INFO 10784 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-05-28 09:23:43.334  INFO 10784 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 401ms. Found 10 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-28 09:23:44.055  INFO 10784 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@508ad266' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-28 09:23:44.060  INFO 10784 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-28 09:23:44.455  INFO 10784 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-05-28 09:23:44.464  INFO 10784 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-28 09:23:44.464  INFO 10784 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-05-28 09:23:44.662  INFO 10784 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/hamster]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-28 09:23:44.662  INFO 10784 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3076 ms
2020-05-28 09:23:44.914  WARN 10784 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-05-28 09:23:44.995  INFO 10784 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 6.4.1 by Redgate
2020-05-28 09:24:01.370 ERROR 10784 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException:
Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:db2://CORRECT_URL;retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;) for user 'CORRECT USER': [jcc][10214][10050][4.26.14] An java.sql.Driver.connect() übergebenes java.util.Properties-Objekt kann von URL nicht überschrieben werden: CORRECT_URL;retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42815
Error Code : -4461

Message    : [jcc][10214][10050][4.26.14] An java.sql.Driver.connect() übergebenes java.util.Properties-Objekt kann von URL nicht überschrieben werden: CORRECT_URL;retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815


2020-05-28 09:24:01.390  INFO 10784 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

2020-05-28 09:24:01.397  WARN 10784 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2020-05-28 09:24:01.410  INFO 10784 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

2020-05-28 09:24:01.419 ERROR 10784 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Here my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And here my application.properties:

```
# Spring Datasource
spring.datasource.url=@DB_URL@
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
spring.datasource.username=@DB_USERNAME@
spring.datasource.password=@DB_PASSWORD@

# JPA / Hibernate
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

# Flyway
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.table=schema_version
spring.flyway.validate-on-migrate=false
spring.flyway.placeholders.tablespace=@FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDER_TABLESPACE@
spring.flyway.placeholders.username=@FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME@
spring.flyway.url=@FLYWAY_DB_URL@
spring.flyway.user=@FLYWAY_DB_USERNAME@
spring.flyway.password=@FLYWAY_DB_PASSWORD@
```

@DB_URL@ = @FLYWAY_DB_URL@
@DB_USERNAME@ != @FLYWAY_DB_USERNAME@

It seems that the connection cannot been updated for the flyway initializer with the credencials from the application.properties.

I have no clue why. I cannot find the abbreviation from the spring / flyway manual I ran into.

Comment: I can spot a typo in spring.slyway.url

Comment: yeah. that came by copying and formatting in this post. My bad i fix that.

Comment: Which version did you use before when it worked?

Comment: Spring-boot parent 2.0.0 and flyware-core 4.2.0

Comment: If I go back to flyway-core 4.2.0 AND introduce a FlywayConfig like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343506/spring-boot-2-1-0-with-flyway-4-2-0 it starts. But I would like to upgrade to 6.4.1

Comment: Spring Boot supports Flyway 6.0.8

Comment: I tried without specifying version and relying on version from spring-boot-parent. Same problem. pom.xml tells me that version inherited from parent would be 6.4.1.

Comment: Tried to explicit set 6.0.8. same problem.